# Array being sent as String on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, socket.io

I am doing some experimenting with socket.io. I have a canvas that successfully sends data to the server which receives it fine.

It receives a Uint8ClampedArray which is correct because that is what is being sent.

When I then .send this message from the server to the client, I get a string: [object Object]. Again I have checked!
Am I missing something, the code for the server is below:

```
var fs, http, io, server;
fs = require('fs');
http = require('http');
server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    return fs.readFile("" + __dirname + "/front.html", function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });
        return res.end(data, 'utf8');
    });
});
server.listen(1337);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('publish', function(message) {
         return io.sockets.send(message);
    });
});
```

Comment: did you tried serializing data before send - JSON.stringify ?

Comment: Convert this array to string or use post to send data

Comment: Ah thank you! JSON.stringify sends the data! Just need to figure out how to convert it back!

Comment: to convert back - JSON.parse()

Comment: Thanks, how do I convert it back to Uint8ClampedArray, that is all Canvas seems to accept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Client:

```
var dataStr = JSON.stringify(data); // converts object to string
```

On Server:

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(data); // converts string to object
```

Comment: I have to do the JSON.parse on the client when it receives the data because when I do it on the server, I get the same problem as before.

Comment: JSON.parse will convert back string to array so you can use at any place where you need this type of conversion. server will always return string so you will need to parse it with these two options I mentioned.

Comment: JSON.parse uses eval at the back, so I prefer using eval.

Comment: Waqar, sorry, eval is a security risk. Just to echo Christoph's outrage, running `eval('client submitted data')` is equivalent to saying, "hey, run any code you want on my server." It opens you up to every security hole imaginable. Don't do it!

Comment: You are right in that case... its just a matter of conversion. For security concerns I would only use JSON.parse

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to reuse `Uint8ClampedArray` in your client size. If you have this on your server-side

```
var x = new Uint8ClampedArray(3);
x[0] = -17;
x[1] = 93;
x[2] = 350;
var dataThatWillBeSent = JSON.stringify(x);
// '{"0":0,"1":93,"2":255,"length":3,"byteLength":3,"byteOffset":0,"buffer":{"byteLength":3}}'
```

In your client side, assume that you have included `Uint8ClampedArray`, you can do this

```
var dataReceived = '{"0":0,"1":93,"2":255,"length":3,"byteLength":3,"byteOffset":0,"buffer":{"byteLength":3}}';
dataReceived = JSON.parse(dataReceived);
// reconstruct Uint8ClampedArray object
```

I have not used `Uint8ClampedArray` before, so I dont know exactly how you can recover a `Uint8ClampedArray` object from a JSON data, but if you read the document you might be able to figure something out